# How to scale dependent variable using StandardScaler

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scaling

When I trying to scale my dependent variable using sklearn StandardScaler, I'm gtting error.

My code is_

```
# Scale the data using sklearn StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

#Creating object of StandardScaler
scale=StandardScaler()

# Scale the dependent variable data using sklearn StandardScaler
y = scale.fit_transform(y)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
y
```

Getting error like this_

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

If I reshape the array can it effect dataframe or model training....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if necessary, you can reshape y to be a 2d array with

```py
y_2d = y.reshape(-1, 1)
y_2d = scale.fit_transform(y_2d)
```

You might not want to scale your y values for several reasons as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re)